# How to sort array into specific format using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need one help. I need to sort an array into a specific format using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$firstArr=array("K"=>"location","L"=>"nearaddrss","M"=>"dsdsfll");
$secondArr=array(array("K"=>"loc","L"=>"Aggggkk","M"=>"dsdsfuu","A"=>"jhkhjg","B"=>"nnnn","C"=>"dsmmmmdsf"),array("K"=>"lo","L"=>"Aggggpp","M"=>"dsdsfjj","A"=>"jhkhjg","B"=>"nnnn","C"=>"dsmmmmdsf"));
$firstResultArr=array();
$secondResultArr=array();
foreach ($firstArr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($secondArr as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($key==$key2){
                $firstResultArr[]=$value;
                $secondResultArr[]=array($value=>$value2);
            }
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($secondResultArr);exit;
```

Here I am getting the output in below format.

```
[{"location":"loc"},{"location":"lo"},{"nearaddrss":"Aggggkk"},{"nearaddrss":"Aggggpp"},{"dsdsfll":"dsdsfuu"},{"dsdsfll":"dsdsfjj"}]
```

But here I need my output like below.

```
[{"location":"loc","nearaddrss":"Aggggkk","dsdsfll":"dsdsfuu"},{"location":"lo","nearaddrss":"Aggggpp","dsdsfll":"dsdsfjj"}]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look.

```
$firstArr=array("K"=>"location","L"=>"nearaddrss","M"=>"dsdsfll");
$secondArr=array(array("K"=>"loc","L"=>"Aggggkk","M"=>"dsdsfuu","A"=>"jhkhjg","B"=>"nnnn","C"=>"dsmmmmdsf"),array("K"=>"lo","L"=>"Aggggpp","M"=>"dsdsfjj","A"=>"jhkhjg","B"=>"nnnn","C"=>"dsmmmmdsf"));
$firstResultArr=array();
$secondResultArr=array();


$firstResultArr=array();
$secondResultArr=array();
foreach($secondArr as $key2 => $val2) {
foreach($val2 as $key3 => $val3) {
foreach ($firstArr as $key => $value) {
$firstResultArr[$value] = $val2[$key];

}
}
$secondResultArr[] =  $firstResultArr;
}

echo json_encode($secondResultArr);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the second array and within that, iterate over the first array like this.

```
<?php
$firstArr=array(
        "K"=>"location",
        "L"=>"nearaddrss",
        "M"=>"dsdsfll"
);

$secondArr=array(
        array(
            "K"=>"loc",
            "L"=>"Aggggkk",
            "M"=>"dsdsfuu",
            "A"=>"jhkhjg",
            "B"=>"nnnn",
            "C"=>"dsmmmmdsf"
        )
        ,array(
                "K"=>"lo",
                "L"=>"Aggggpp",
                "M"=>"dsdsfjj",
                "A"=>"jhkhjg",
                "B"=>"nnnn",
                "C"=>"dsmmmmdsf")
        );

$result = array();

foreach ($secondArr as $key2 => $value2) {
    $item = array();
    foreach ($firstArr as $key => $value) {
        $item[$value] = $value2[$key];
    }
    $result[] = $item;
}

echo json_encode($result);
die();
```